# Unable to add Styling for Django Template

Tags: javascript, css, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have created a HTML page using Django,where I have four different categories of forms named as Live, Report, Planning and Old. These four categories of forms are connected with SQL server to show various sub-forms under these categories. I can get all the forms here and my below code is working fine.
The name of the Page is  "FORM TRACKING APP".I have added two more logics here which shows the different user names when they logged in and a logout link. Here the user name and logout is in the top right of the page, also below that I have link which creates new form.

About the styling I am facing few issues that I want to do.
1.I want to create a fixed Navbar where it shows the page name in the middle and shows user name in the right side of the bar with an image and also with the logout link.
2.Want to replace link for Add new form with a button.
3.Want to create borders for four categories of forms.

My code is given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><b><center><u>FORM TRACKING APP</u></center></b></h1>
  
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <div class="topright">User: Hi {{ user.get_username }} !! <br><a href="{% url 'logout' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Logout</a><br></div>
   
    
  {% endif %}

  
  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
.topright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.blue-bg {
  background-color: rgb(0, 174, 255);
}

.head-button-size {
  height: 66px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.head-material {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.head-mini-text {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Arial Narrow', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial';
  font-size: 12px;
}
.tooltip-text {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #192733;
  padding: 5px;
}

.addform{
  float: right;
  color :rgb(0, 174, 255);
  text-decoration-color: aqua;
  text-emphasis: True;
  font-size: larger;
}

</style>
<html>
<a href="{% url 'add' %}" class="addform">+ Add Form</a>
<h2>Live</h2>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<table>
  <tr>
    {% if formversion_list %}
      {% for form in formversion_list %}
      {% if form.get_live %}
          <td style="height:66px;">
            <button class="head-button-size blue-bg" ui-sref="start">
                  <div style="text-align:center">
                    <md-icon class="material-icons head-material">domain</md-icon>
                    <br>
                    <a class="head-mini-text" href="{% url 'form-detail' form.form_version_id %}">{{ form.form_version_nm }} - {{ form.form_version_cd }}</a>
                  </div>
                </button>
          </td>
      {% else %}
      <!--<p> No forms to display in this category</p>-->
    {% endif %} 
    {% endfor %} 
    {% else %}
     <p> No forms to display</p>
    {% endif %}
  </tr>
</table>

<h2>Report</h2>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<table>
  <tr>
    {% if formversion_list %}
      {% for form in formversion_list %}
      {% if form.get_formfreeze %}
          <td style="height:66px;">
            <button class="head-button-size blue-bg" ui-sref="start">
                  <div style="text-align:center">
                    <md-icon class="material-icons head-material">domain</md-icon>
                    <br>
                    <a class="head-mini-text" href="{% url 'form-detail' form.form_version_id %}">{{ form.form_version_nm }} - {{ form.form_version_cd }}</a>
                  </div>
                </button>
          </td>
        {% else %}
        <!-- <p> No forms in this category </p> -->
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
     <p> No forms to display</p>
    {% endif %}
  </tr>
</table>

<h2>Planning</h2>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<table>
  <tr>
    {% if formversion_list %}
      {% for form in formversion_list %}
        {% if form.get_planning_formdev %}
        
          <td style="height:66px;">
            <button class="head-button-size blue-bg" ui-sref="start">
                  <div style="text-align:center">
                    <md-icon class="material-icons head-material">domain</md-icon>
                    <br>
                    <a class="head-mini-text" href="{% url 'form-detail' form.form_version_id %}">{{ form.form_version_nm }} - {{ form.form_version_cd }}</a>
                  </div>
                </button>
          </td>
        {% else %}
        <!-- <p> No forms in this category </p> -->
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
     <p> No forms to display</p>
    {% endif %}
  </tr>
</table>

<h2>Old</h2>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<table>
  <tr>
    {% if formversion_list %}
      {% for form in formversion_list %}
      {% if form.get_retired %}
          <td style="height:66px;">
            <button class="head-button-size blue-bg" ui-sref="start">
                  <div style="text-align:center">
                    <md-icon class="material-icons head-material">domain</md-icon>
                    <br>
                    <a class="head-mini-text" href="{% url 'form-detail' form.form_version_id %}">{{ form.form_version_nm }} - {{ form.form_version_cd }}</a>
                  </div>
                </button>
          </td>
        {% else %}
        <!-- <p> No forms in this category </p> -->
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
     <p> No forms to display</p>
    {% endif %}
  </tr>
</table>


</html>

</body>
</html>
```

I am learning HTML,CSS,JS, and D-jango, so unable to add the styling part for my code as mentioned above. Need help, how to resolve this.

Answer (score -1):

For a start

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> <!-- DELETE THIS.
<style>
.topright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

You have one on the top of your HTML file.

```
</style>
<html>  <!-- DELETE THIS.
<a href="{% url 'add' %}" class="addform">+ Add Form</a>
<h2>Live</h2>
```

You already have one...

All of your linked stylesheets should be between the head tags, and you shouldn't link the same resource more than once.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```